# cannot upgrade laravel version to 7 from 6.20.8

Tags: laravel

[image]

this is my composer.json

```json
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "1.1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.0",
        "yoeunes/toastr": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8"
    },
```

it return requesting for laravel/ui v1.1.0 but i have already installed.

i have tried composer install, composer update but still the same problem.

Comment: @KamleshPaul so i have to upgrade "laravel/ui" to 2.4.0 version?

Comment: @KamleshPaul i tried but error return. 
Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v6.20.8, required as ^7.29) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.20.8] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: @KamleshPaul i cant put screen shot on the comment, i put as answer as below

Comment: @KamleshPaul i removed and run the composer require laravel/ui "^2.4" but it return the same error. or i need run other command?

Comment: show me screen shot

Comment: @KamleshPaul same message as below image

Comment: it cannot be local if your remove that file

Comment: so i have to remove the composer.lock file or not?

Comment: you have to delete that file it will generated once you run `composer update`

Comment: yes i have deleted the file but after i run the `composer update` it return same error as above image i post first time

Comment: `"laravel/ui": "1.1",` upgrade this

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is after i tried composer require laravel/ui "^2.4" return result